# Azure timing out connections at 5m, use keep-alive?

Tags: c#, timeout, keep-alive

I'm debugging a middle-tier service that occasionally makes long-running requests (~15m) to a 3rd-party service, for calling clients.

Anytime the request takes longer than 5m, the following exception is seen at the caller/client:

```
System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server.
---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host ...
```

The client is setting its Timeout and ReadWriteTimeout to 15m. Research suggests that I need to use TCP keep-alive to keep the connection between the client and the middle-tier service open for the duration of the request.

I'd like to start using:

```
var httpRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp(new Uri("https://someendpoint"));
httpRequest.ServicePoint.SetTcpKeepAlive(true, 120 * 1000, 120 * 1000);
```

My concern is that I'm already using the following to enforce load balancing changes via DNS, and I don't know how the two interact:

```
httpRequest.ServicePoint.ConnectionLeaseTimeout = 30 * 1000;
```

I want to make sure that the introduction of `SetTcpKeepAlive` won't affect the desired behavior of opening a new `ServicePoint` roughly every 30 seconds. I understand that the long-running request will still be tied to the old `ServicePoint` object until it finishes, but I want to make sure that:

- every 30 seconds (roughly), new requests are given to a new
  `ServicePoint`, in case of failovers / DNS changes
- long-running
  requests are able to use keep-alive to keep the middle-tier service
  from dropping the connection due to it being idle while waiting for
  the 3rd party service to respond